# Date timezone issue JPA with jackson

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jpa, jackson

I am storing date in PostGreSql as

```
CREATE TABLE "Transaction"
(
  "Id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   "DateTimeInUTC" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()),
);
```

In mapping entity

```
@Column(name = "\"DateTimeInUTC\"", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateTimeInUTC
```

In the POJO class there are simple getter, setter methods for dateTimeInUTC.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT, timezone = "UTC")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "date for the transaction ", position = 2, required = true)
public Date getDateTimeInUTC() {        
}
```

When I run my application database have correct date in UTC. But the response JSON I am getting have wrong entry for the "DateTimeInUTC". It is not same as database.

Does any one have idea how can I match the database date and response json date?

Comment: "It is not same as database." - could you provide examples of what you're seeing at each point? The more information we have, the better...

Comment: JPA provider retrieves WHAT? JPA != JSON. So separate the description out into what happens in JPA to get the data back into Java objects, then what JSON does with it. aka debugging

Comment: Hi Jon, I am in IST. Current time is 3.06 pm. Now I store the entity. Data base entry is "2017-06-27 09:36:51.37448" which is correct in UTC format and json response is "2017-06-27 04:06:51.374+0000" which looks +1 hour.